# CAML: Filter URL field on description (not on URL)

Tags: caml-query

I have a list with an URL-field. Nothing special, just the OOTB Hyperlink-field.

I want to execute a CAML-query that selects items with a certain value in the description part of the URL-field.

**CAML**

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Contains>
      <FieldRef Name="URL" />
      <Value Type="URL">text</Value>
    </Contains>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

**Result**
Only items with 'text' in de url part are selected, if a item has 'text' in the description part it is *not* selected.

How do i select items based the description of the URL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you won't be able to do this with a CAML query. This is because for 'complex' fields which store multiple values, only the 'default' value is available to query - by this I mean what would be available when SPField.GetFieldValueAsText() is called.

This would mean the only way to 'query' like this is to iterate through the items in the list.

Comment: Thanks, for now i just added an extra column which duplicates the value of the description and use that for filtering.

Comment: If this is the solution. It will take more time to show the Results..